# how can use ShellExecute Function to send image or PDF file to WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

Can you help me,
how can use ShellExecute Function to send image or PDF file to WhatsApp
Thank you and regards

I'm used ShellExecute Function to send message will done and I hope to help me how to use ShellExecute Function to send media to WhatsApp
or any way to solve this problem